# A screen capturing tool that allows me to annonatate screenshots before saving them

Tags: shortcut-keys, software-recommendation, screenshot, capture

I'm seeking for an excellent screen-capture programme that allows me to do the following:

- Annotate screenshots
- Can be run from the command line or via keybindings

I'll appreciate if it also offers these features:

- Capable of taking a screenshot of a specific area
- Capable of saving screenshots in a specific directory on demand.
- Capable of not displaying any graphical user interface dialogue boxes (If asked)

I'm on Ubuntu 21.10 with Gnome Desktop.

<sub>I understand that there may not be a single programme to address all of these concerns. As a result, I have no objection in using more than one software (these softwares should be launched via different keybindings)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Flameshot

It is my personal favorite screenshot application, which can be installed using:

```
$ sudo apt install flameshot
```

By default, you need to launch it using GUI but you can easily set a screenshot for flameshot by following these steps:

1. Head to the system settings and navigate your way to the Keyboard settings.
2. You will find all the keyboard shortcuts listed there, ignore them and scroll down to the bottom. Now, you will find a `+` button.
3. Click the `+` button to add a custom shortcut.
4. You need to enter the following in the fields you get:
   Name: *Anything You Want*
   Command: `/usr/bin/flameshot gui`
5. Finally, set the shortcut to <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> – which will warn you that the default screenshot functionality will be disabled – so proceed doing it. 
   <sup><sub>[Reference](https://itsfoss.com/take-screenshot-linux/)</sub></sup>

You can easily configure it to suite your needs. Just press <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> and it'll open a selection tool. Selct the desired area, do customizations and easily save it.

Features:

- Annotate (highlight, point, add text, box in)
- Blur part of an image
- Crop part of an image
- **Upload to [Imgur](https://imgur.com) (copies the link of the image to your clip board, no additional apps or accounts needed)**
- Open screenshot with another app

[image: Features]

You can easily press the save button to save the image. In the app settings, you can also choose the default directory to save images in. It also have a lot of customisable key-bindings and features.